# How can I properly get a discord channel using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have attempted to create a bot that moves two users into a private voice channel, but I keep on getting the error "The "Private Channel" voice channel was not found."

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'move') {
    if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('MOVE_MEMBERS')) {
      return interaction.reply('You do not have permission to move members.');
    }

    const userOption = interaction.options.getUser('user');
    const userTwoOption = interaction.options.getUser('user-two');

    if (!userOption || !userTwoOption) {
      return interaction.reply('Please provide two users to move.');
    }

    const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (c) => c.type === 'GUILD_VOICE' && c.name === 'Private Channel'
    );

    if (!channel) {
      return interaction.reply('The "Private Channel" voice channel was not found.');
    }

    try {
      await userOption.voice.setChannel(channel);
      await userTwoOption.voice.setChannel(channel);
      interaction.reply('Users moved successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      interaction.reply('An error occurred while moving the users.');
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried to run this using different ways to get the voice channel, although none of them have worked at all.

Comment: What is your discord.js version ? Did you have voice channel named: "Private Channel"

Comment: @HellCatVN Where can I check the discord.js version, and yes the voice channel exists.

Comment: is `find` return values at `const channel` try to simplify it with filter c.name only first. will it have value if not try to fetch it instead get from cache. Discord.js version is at package.json file

Comment: @HellCatVN I seemed to have done something with the code and now it works perfectly fine? Although i cannot check if the user has permission to move members without it crashing (it seems to crash when someone without perms tries to run the command) It says "Invalid bitfield flag or number" would you have any idea why?

Comment: You can raise new question I will try to look when I am free seem not relate to this question